# What should we use for ClientResponse and GenericType in latest version (3.0.x) Resteasy?

Tags: resteasy, deprecated

I am developing `Resteasy`. I migrated my application's maven dependencies from `2.2.x` to `3.0.x` and suddenly I saw most of the API's are deprecated. So this migration has affect to my code and test cases as its simply saying deprecated in my whole code.

I am taking example of my test cases:
Test case with earlier version(in latest version it deprectaed as mentioned in link: **[ClientRequestFactory RestEasy Deprecated... Any other RestEasy alternative ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413111/clientrequestfactory-resteasy-deprecated-any-other-resteasy-alternative#comment44157420_18415852)**):

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.util.GenericType;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponse;

@Test
    public void testGetStudent() throws Exception{
        String str = "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/restwebservice/list";
        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(str);
        ClientResponse<List<Student>> response = request.get(new GenericType<List<Student>>(){});
        List<Student> students = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("Size : "+students.size());
    }
```

So I refactore my test case to use

```
@Test
    public void testGetStudents(){
        final String str = "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/restwebservice/list";
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        // Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();  // This also works, OR

        Response response = client.target(str).request().get();

        // This will gives us whole XML output
        String s = response.readEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(s);

**What is the replacement of below two lines in latest version? How I can get List of Student Object ?**
//      ClientResponse<List<Student>> response = request.get(new GenericType<List<Student>>(){});
//      List<Student> students = response.getEntity();
    }
```

Please guide. **What is the replacement of below two lines in latest version? How I can get List of Student Object ?**

[image]

Edit-1: I tried below, but giving following error:
Students.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "students")
public class Students {

    @XmlElement(name="student")
    private ArrayList<Student> users;

    public ArrayList<Student> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(ArrayList<Student> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

But its giving me errors:

```
@Test
    public void testGetStudents(){
        final String str = "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/restwebservice/list";
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        // Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();  // This also works, OR

        Response response = client.target(str).request().get();

        // This will gives us whole XML output
        String stringOutput = response.readEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("STATUS : "+response.getStatus());
        System.out.println(stringOutput);


        Students students = response.readEntity(Students.class);
        System.out.println("Size : "+students.getUsers().size());
    }


java.lang.IllegalStateException: RESTEASY003765: Response is closed.
    at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.abortIfClosed(BuiltResponse.java:256)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.abortIfClosed(ClientResponse.java:328)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:219)
    at com.mkyong.rest.test.RestEasySampleTest.testGetStudents(RestEasySampleTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: I think 'asap' usually results in zero answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Resteasy Client-API has been [marked deprecated](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2013/06/18/resteasy-3-0-final-released/) as JAX-RS standardized a Client-API. You can now use the equivalent `javax.ws.rs` classes:

```java
javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget target = client.target("someUrl");
List<Student> students = 
    target.request().get(new javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType<List<Student>>() {});
```

Comment: RESTeasy is an implementation of the JAX-RS API. As already explained in the linked answer: RESTeasy 2.x shipped with some kind of extension which was standardized by JAX-RS 2 so there was no need any more for the RESTeasy Client API.

Comment: Ok, Appreciated info from you. !

Comment: Could you please guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310699/org-codehaus-jackson-map-jsonmappingexception-can-not-deserialize-instance-of-j

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with query parameters and a check for the HTTP response code, which is handy for failing fast and avoiding stack traces from the JSON mapper, often hiding the real cause:

```
Response response = null;
try {
  response = target.path("apiMethod")
                .queryParam("stringParam", "test")
                .queryParam("booleanParam", Boolean.FALSE)
                .request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

  if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode()) { // HTTP 400
    throw new BadRequestException("invalid parameters!");
  } else if (response.getStatus() == 
    Response.Status.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode()) {  // HTTP 404
        throw new NotFoundException("resource was not found on server!");
  }

    List<MyPojo> result = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<MyPojo>>(){});
    return result;
} finally {
  if (response != null) {
    response.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you're checking for errors you should also use `try{...}finally{response.close();}`

Comment: thanks for the hint @Delfic, added that to my answer.

Comment: Good, but that won't compile
You need either a try with resources or to define the Response outside of the try and then check for null in the finally

Comment: ah ok fixed @Delfic - sadly, javax.ws.rs.core.Response is not autoclosable, so no luck with try-with-resources unfortunately.